# Scala parsing recursively to arbitrary output values

Tags: scala, parsing

How would I use scala combinators to take a string such as ((0)+0) and make it so every parenthesis I would take the power of two to the inside of the parenthesis recursively. (0)+0= 2^2^0 = 5.  How could I take an input string and produce an integer output. The recursive part and the addition part are killing me. I have this so far, but am struggling with the next and start portion, and how to relate these to numbers.

```
  def Parens:Parser[Int] = """(""" ~remainder ~ """)"""  
  def Plus = term ~ '+' ~ remainder .map(_=> atom + remainder) //Also pseudocode and don't know how to implement this. 
  def Term = parens .map(_=>2^remainder) //This line is pseudocode, can't implement this correctly
  def zero: Parser[Int] = literal("0").map(_ => 0)
  def remainder:Parser[Int] =(Next|Start|zero) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of implementing a Parser for your problem. I maybe misunderstood the `+` operation in your examples. e.g. I would evaluate `(0) + 0` to `2^0 + 0 = 1 + 0 = 1`, but that should be easy to fix if you explain it more detailed. I included all your examples.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object ParserTest extends App {

  object MyParser extends RegexParsers {
    private lazy val zero: Parser[Int] = "0" ^^^ { 0 }

    private lazy val parens: Parser[Int] = "(" ~> exp <~ ")" ^^ { e => Math.pow(2, e).toInt }

    private lazy val term: Parser[Int] = parens | zero

    private lazy val plus: Parser[Int] = term ~ "+" ~ term ~ rep("+" ~> term) ^^
          { case t0 ~ "+" ~ t1 ~ rest => rest.foldLeft(t0 + t1)(_ + _) }

    private lazy val exp: Parser[Int] = plus | term

    def evaluate(input: String) = parseAll(exp, input)
  }

  println(MyParser.evaluate("0"))                   //0
  println(MyParser.evaluate("(0)"))                 //1
  println(MyParser.evaluate("((0))"))               //2
  println(MyParser.evaluate("(0)+0"))               //1
  println(MyParser.evaluate("((0)+0)"))             //2
  println(MyParser.evaluate("(0)+((0))+ ((0)+0)"))  //5

}
```

Comment: Yea, I need explanation on the `+` operation. `(0) -> 2^0 = 1`. `0 -> 0` So `(0) + 0` is `2^0 + 0 = 1`.

Comment: The `((0)+(0))` example results in `4` with the parser. I need examples of things that do not work and why they don't work. Or a formal description. I think you should edit your question with the new examples and check for possible mistakes.